# How can i match a string to a specific format using regex?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I need to validate a string against the following:

1. Must begin with AB - the only two letters
2. Must contain at least 5 digits
3. Must not contain non alphanumeric characters

The format would be AB12345.

The code i'd be using would be:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("REGEX PARRERN HERE")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match(SOURCE STRING)
```

What regex pattern could i use to do this? I don't know where to start...

Why the downvotes?, stackoverflow can be a hostile place...

Comment: Can you provide an example of what should match? Do the digits need to be next to each other?

Comment: [You can start here](https://regex101.com/r/cQ5cN3/1) and then include your regex within your answer to show where you got stuck.

Comment: I'd have made more of an effort with a pattern if i knew where to start

Comment: @SamJones: You can find lots of useful posts on SO that can solve your problem. It is difficult to find exact duplicate for you, but there are many similar ones. Just search for "string validation", "regex password validation", etc. I see it is VB.NET. You do not really have to use any regex for that check even. Use LINQ and string methods.

Comment: i looked at existing stackoverflow questions, but none i could find matched a limited number of letters with an unlimited number of digits

Comment: AB is at the start and if only digits remain, you can just remove it from the string, remove non-alnum and check the length of the remainder.

Comment: wont [**something like this**](https://regex101.com/r/aL3kG2/2) work for you?

Comment: thanks @benjaminS, exactly what i needed. If you post your comment as an answer i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: actually @benjaminS, i still need to make it exclude non alphanumeric characters

Comment: @SamJones: Why not use `Dim s As String = "AB123455" //
        If s.StartsWith("AB") = False Or _ //
           s.Count(Function(m) Char.IsDigit(m)) < 5 Or _ //
           s.Any(Function(m) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(m) = False) Then //
            MsgBox("Bad string!") //
        End If`?

Answer (score 0):

With the updated requirements, a simple `^AB([0-9]){5,}` should do.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't the dialect i can use, I've updated my question with my usage example.

Comment: I don't see it - what is the dialect you want to use? I can't tell if that is some sort of BASIC or something else. It'd be easiest if you point me to its online docs wrt regex.

Comment: It is .NET, Visual Basic .NET.